# Magento default wording if price is £0.00

Tags: php, magento

I have a selection of products within my wordpress site.

They are configurable products with different prices for each product except the main configurable product which holds them all is £0.00.

On the product pages it shows £0.00 first until an option is selected from the dropdown which changes the price.

My question is it possible for there to be some default wording if the price is £0.00 but if an option gets choosen it will show the price.

I am thinking something like an `if` statement to see if the value is £0.00 show "Choose an option" but if  a product is selected from the dropdown it will change that wording to the price of the product choosen which is the default at the moment.

I do show the Excl VAT and Incl Vat so need them to both have the same function.

At the moment the Excl Vat is using

`<?php if ($_finalPrice == $_price): ?>
                            <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_price, true, false) ?>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_finalPrice, true, false) ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>`

And Incl Vat is

`<?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_finalPriceInclTax, true, false) ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix for this using the code below:

`<?php if($_product->price==0): ?>
    <?php echo '<span class="price-excluding-tax-2588">Choose an option from below</span>'; ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
<?php endif; ?>`